# I have an slsb in ejb3.0 with a number of methods, do I need to annotate each method with transaction attributes?

Tags: jpa, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

class decalaration:

```
@Stateless
@Local( { IMyLocalSLSB.class })
@Remote( { IMyRemoteSLSB.class }) })
public class mySLSB implements IMySLSB {

private EntityManager em;
```

and now some methods for inserting/updating and deleting db records are transactions annotations required, I thought they were not as jboss and EJB3.0 handle them using defaults:

```
public void crud(MyEntity myEntity)  {
    em.merge(myEntity);// inserts or updates    
}

public void deleteInsert(MyEntity myEntity)  {

    MyEntity found = em.find(MyEntity.class, myEntity.getMyEntityPK());

    if (found == null) {
        em.merge(myEntity);
    } else {
        em.remove(found);
    }   
}
```

And finally, is this the best way to return a record/entity but not persist any further changes. I take a record and alter the data and then display (I could put into a DTO but this seems neater/less objects)

```
public MyEntity getAnEntity(integer id){

    MyEntity myEntity = em.find(MyEntity.class, id);
    org.hibernate.Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
    session.evict(myEntity);
    return myEntity;
}
```

To summarizes are annotation requried on methods for transactions in an slsb, and is session.evict the best way to stop any changes being persisted ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To summarizes are annotation required on methods for transactions in an SLSB

No, they are **not required**. You **can** apply the `@TransactionAttribute` annotation at the class-level to specify the default transaction attribute for all business methods of the enterprise bean. If you do not, your bean will default to `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)` (i.e. all  methods are  transacted by default).

> and is `session.evict` the best way to stop any changes being persisted?

- JPA 1.0 has [`EntityManager#clear()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) but this would clear the **whole** persistence context.

  - If not wanted, then falling back to [`Session#evict(Object)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) is indeed the best option.
- Unless you're using JPA 2.0 in which case there is [`EntityManager#detach(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29) now.